# Mashape Objective-C for iOS - MashapeResponse to JSON Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, lambda, mashape

I am consuming an API through Mashape.com called Lamda (https://www.mashape.com/lambda) a face recognition API.

When I get my result back from the recognize request it gives me a "MashapeRespose" object.

I cannot convert this MashapeResponse or any of its parts into a JSON object.

When I call

```
NSLog(@"des=%@", [response body]);
```

I get this printed out

```
{
    images =     (
        "http://api.lambdal.com/static/uploads/img05Xv8N.png"
    );
    photos =     (
                {
            height = 241;
            tags =             (
                                {
                    attributes =                     (
                                                {
                            confidence = "0.7097208087892503";
                            gender = male;
                        }
                    );
                    center =                     {
                        x = 95;
                        y = 98;
                    };
                    confidence = "0.978945010372561";
                    "eye_left" =                     {
                        x = 114;
                        y = 84;
                    };
                    "eye_right" =                     {
                        x = 76;
                        y = 85;
                    };
                    height = 112;
                    "mouth_center" =                     {
                        x = "96.5";
                        y = "134.5";
                    };
                    "mouth_left" =                     {
                        x = 74;
                        y = "134.5";
                    };
                    "mouth_right" =                     {
                        x = 119;
                        y = "134.5";
                    };
                    nose =                     {
                        x = 94;
                        y = 113;
                    };
                    tid = 31337;
                    uids =                     (
                                                {
                            confidence = "0.323";
                            prediction = manuel;
                            uid = "manuel@MICClientele";
                        },
                                                {
                            confidence = "0.194";
                            prediction = olivier;
                            uid = "olivier@MICClientele";
                        },
                                                {
                            confidence = "0.161";
                            prediction = sean;
                            uid = "sean@MICClientele";
                        },
                                                {
                            confidence = "0.161";
                            prediction = damien;
                            uid = "damien@MICClientele";
                        },
                                                {
                            confidence = "0.065";
                            prediction = egle;
                            uid = "egle@MICClientele";
                        },
                                                {
                            confidence = "0.065";
                            prediction = gareth;
                            uid = "gareth@MICClientele";
                        }
                    );
                    width = 112;
                }
            );
            url = "http://api.lambdal.com/static/uploads/img05Xv8N.png";
            width = 200;
        }
    );
    status = success;
}
```

Obviously this is not valid JSON.

Here is the contents of MashapeResponse.h

```
#import "MashapeResponse.h"

@interface MashapeResponse ()
@property (readwrite, retain) NSData* rawBody;
@property (readwrite) NSDictionary* headers;
@property (readwrite) int code;
@end

@implementation MashapeResponse

@synthesize rawBody;
@synthesize headers;
@synthesize code;
@synthesize body;

-(MashapeResponse*)initWithResponse:(int)httpCode headers:(NSDictionary*) httpHeaders rawBody:(NSData*) httpRawBody {
    self = [super init];
    [self setCode:httpCode];
    [self setHeaders:httpHeaders];
    [self setRawBody:httpRawBody];
    return self;
}

@end
```

Has anyone been able to use Mashape on iOS and been able to convert into a JSON object?

I can use substring to get the info I want but this is not how it should work since the docs state its should be a json response..

Very frustrated to say the least...

Regards
Damien

PS. I have mailed Mashape support with this question so if I get a solution back before someone posts an answer here i will add it to this post.

Edit:

When I call

```
id status = [response valueForKey:@"status"];
NSLog(@"status=%@", [status description]);
id photos = [response valueForKey:@"photos"];
NSLog(@"photos=%@", [photos description]);
```

I get this exception

```
2012-09-20 16:53:20.609 Clientele[5160:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MashapeJsonObjectResponse 0x3d2810> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key status.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly thanks you Dcritelli for your help with this issue..

I got a reply from Mashape about my issue and they sent me this email in reply.

---

> Hi Damien,
>
> The [response body] method already returns a parsed JSON object. If
>   you need the raw response in bytes (that is a NSData* object), you can
>   get it by invoking [response rawBody]. You can convert a NSData* to
>   NSString* if you want.
>
> Given that [response body] returns the parsed JSON object, for example
>   to get the "url" property of the first photo in the "photos" array,
>   you would write:

```
 NSArray* photos = [[response body] objectForKey:@"photos"];
 NSDictionary* firstPhoto = [photos objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString* url = [firstPhoto objectForKey:@"url"];
 NSLog(@"URL of the first photo is: %@", url);
```

> We apologize if the docs were confusing, we updated them and you can
>   read the new revision here:
>   https://www.mashape.com/docs/consume/objectivec
>
> Let us know if you need additional help, Cheers

---

So not only have they replied with a solution they have also updated their documentation.

Hats off to Mashape.

Regards
Damien

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a dictionary object. There should be keys listed in the api description. Just use:

```
[response valueForKey:@"key"]
```

And assign the value to the appropriate object: array, dictionary, or whatever it happens to be.

Comment: That's the thing its a MashapeResponse and not a NSMutableArray or a NSMutableDictionary... Its a MashapeResponse. the docs say the protocol should be 

-(void)requestCompleted:(id) response

but it is 

-(void)requestCompleted:(MashapeResponse*) response
{
    if([response isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]){
        NSLog(@"NSMutableDictionary=%@", [response body]);
    }else if([response isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]){
        NSLog(@"NSMutableArray=%@", [response body]);
    }
}

Comment: I used the netcetera api. It may be different, but for me sending the MashapeResponse object the key for the object you want works. I think it stores the actual json and parses it for you.

Comment: Also, I assume you've read it, but just in case. Here are the docs:
https://www.mashape.com/docs/consume/objectivec

Comment: This is the Lambda API I am consuming: https://www.mashape.com/lambda/face-recognition#Recognize

The response it shows is JSON but the response I get has ; for ,

Comment: I added some info into the original question above at the end. These comments do not have good formatting...

Comment: How are you sending the request to begin with?

Comment: NSString * url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"me"ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"faces"];
    NSURL * face = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];

    [face_recognition_api recognizeWithCallback:kAlbum_name albumkey:kAlbum_key files:face urls:@"" callback:self];